# How to track route taken in IONIC 2 and save it in database

Tags: php, mysql, ionic2

Good day, I'm new to IONIC 2.. i'm creating an app where it can track the route the users took and save it to the database, where another user is going to view his/her route by a PHP webpage.. I was following this link here: https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-background-geolocation-to-an-ionic-2-application/

I just want to know if you have any idea on how to save this in mysql database?

Many thanks!

Comment: You have to send this coordinates to an API that writes in your mysql.

Comment: thanks Christian, the real problem is how do i save the track route.. on the link it just displays the GPS coordinates on the phone, my problem is how can i get it all from the start of the trip till the end of the trip.. and send it to an API? any idea?

Comment: I'd send it as JSON data back to the server, which then disseminates it.